# Android & Apple Push Notifcations

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, push

I have an app set for push notification. The Android code works fine and I receive a push notification. For Apple, the phone just vibrates and makes sound for push notifications, but I don't get a badge or anything else.

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

```
<?php
// function to send Android push notification

function send_message($deviceToken, $message){
    $messageArr['message'] = "";
    if($message=="")
    {
         $messageArr['message'] = "Test data";
    }
    else
    {
             $messageArr['message'] = $message ;
    }
    $registatoin_ids = $deviceToken;
    return mer_send_notification($registatoin_ids, $messageArr);

}

function mer_curlPost($url, $headers, $fields) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}



function mer_send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$apiKey = 'mykeyishere';
echo 'Test if 4\n';
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => $message,
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$result = mer_curlPost($url, $headers, $fields);
return $result;
}
function sendNotification($dataArr, $device_token_array) {

$apns_url = NULL;
$apns_cert = NULL;
$apns_port = 2195;
$development = false;
if ($development) {
    $apns_url = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
        $apns_cert = 'devcert.pem';
} else {
    $apns_url = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
    $apns_cert = 'prodcert.pem';
}
$stream_context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apns_cert);
stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'mypassphrase');
$payload = array();
$payload['aps'] = $dataArr;
$payloadJson = json_encode($payload);
$apns = @stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apns_url . ':' . $apns_port, $error, $error_string, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);

foreach ($device_token_array as $key => $device_token) {
    $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payloadJson)) . $payloadJson;
    $xxx[] = @fwrite($apns, $apns_message);
}
$yyy = @socket_close($apns);
$zzz = @fclose($apns);
$arr = array();
$arr[] = $stream_context;
$arr[] = $apns;
$arr[] = $xxx;
$arr[] = $yyy;
$arr[] = $zzz;
return $arr;
}
```

Comment: check ur $dataArr Which you are adding as ur payload..

Comment: Jitendra should i use the same messageArr that i have used for andriod?

Comment: You need to create your payload body as.pass your message and badge on it ..and if you want to customize sound then add ur custom sound on place of defalut..
$payload['aps'] = array(
    'badge' => 1,
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
);

Comment: Jitendra i added replaced the line $payload['aps'] = $dataArr; with $payload['aps'] = array( 'badge' => 1, 'alert' => $dataArr, 'sound' => 'default' );  and i get the same thing iphone vibrates but no badge or message

Answer (score 0):

The notification format for iOS is different than for Android. See here for iOS format: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1